# Static Instance Thread Safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a strategy pattern implementation as below:

```
    public class ConcreteStrategy implements Strategy {

         public static final Strategy INSTANCE = new ConcreteStrategy();

         public AClass execute(AClass aClass){
              //...do somthing
              return aClass;
         }
    }
```

Ignoring the bad practice of returning the input parameter, is static instance INSTANCE use thread safe?

Comment: By the way: add a private constructor so you know nobody is creating another instance of ConcreteStrategy (in case that's the wanted behavior :)

Comment: And make the class `final` whilst you're about it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ConcreteStrategy` isn't modified, or is modified only in a thread-safe way, then yes. The `final` modifier will ensure (in Java 1.5+) that all threads see the `INSTANCE` object in at least the state it was in when the class was initialized. Any subsequent change to the object would need to be made thread-safe in the usual way (through volatiles, synchronization, classes that provide thread-safety, etc).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong: when I call the function a object reference copy is passed to the method, so each time the method executes on a different object.
The class is used in a webapp, the calls share only the code?

Comment: @landal79: Java passes copies of the references. So "aClass" param is a copy of the reference. BUT the AClass object being used and returned is the same. Think of it as pointers. You can pass along pointers, copy of pointers, and whatever, but the pointed object is the same. If there's ONE `new`, there's ONE object.

Comment: The "final field semantics" of the new JMM are irrelevant here. All threads will see a fully initialised `ConcreteStrategy` class once that static initialiser has finished its work, so long as it doesn't do something really stupid.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Why is that? As far as I can see in the JLS, the only synchronization that happens around class initialization is that a thread gets a lock on the class during initialization. If the class is already initialized when the thread sees it for the first time, the thread won't synchronize on it, and thus there's no happens-before relationship between the static's initialization and this thread's reading of the field. I believe the other thread would be able to see a null reference or partially constructed object. It'd be rare, but allowed by the JLS.

Comment: @yshavit See the dozen step process at the bottom of section 5.5 of the Java SE 7 JVM spec. "For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock LC. [Blah, blah, blah.]"

Comment: Besides, final field semantics related to instance fields in constructors.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline The JVM spec contains tighter requirements than the JLS spec.

Answer (score 2):

Generally any Object in java that is immutable or stateless is Thread-safe.

Your example is *almost* thread safe.

The **reference** to INSTANCE is thread-safe, since it's final. But the contents of the ConcreteStrategy might be very well not Thread safe (we do not see the code, thus can't tell).

**If you provide proper** synchronization to the  ConcreteStrategy Object, then it could be very well a Thread safe Object.

Cheers, Eugene.

Comment: suppose that `execute()` method executes only on the parameter

Comment: @landal79 I didn't understand what you mean by executes only one parameter. Could you be a bit more verbose plz?

Comment: `execute()` method do some evaluation on `aClass` instance fields value, and the ConcreteStrategy class has no internal state is only an algorithm.

Comment: @landal79 if as you say ConcreteStrategy has no internal state - and by that you mean it has no instance variables (internal state) and has only a method, then yes it is thread safe.